# How to properly check if an html textbox is empty

Tags: php

I always get the undefined index notice, when I run this on wampserver. Tried doing some [research](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/empty-and-isset-in-php/) before going here, and I integrated the code into this, but still no luck. Please help.

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_GET['lurl']) || ($_GET['lclass']) || ($_GET['lnotes'])) {

    $url=$_GET['lurl'];
    $clas=$_GET['lclass'];
    $notez=$_GET['lnotes'];



    $sql="CALL geturl('$url')";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql);

    ?>

                <center>

    <table border="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>CLASS</th>
        <th>NOTES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){


    ?>


        <tbody>
                <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['URL']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Class']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Notes']; ?></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 1st line

```
if(!empty($_GET['lurl']) || ($_GET['lclass']) || ($_GET['lnotes']))
```

Must be

```
if(!empty($_GET['lurl']) || !empty($_GET['lclass']) || !empty($_GET['lnotes']))
```

Reference for empty function http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I still get the notice of undefined index when I used this